# Suppose that $a,c$ are real numbers ,$c>0$ and $f$ is defined on $[0,1]$ by....

Tags: real-analysis, limits, derivatives, continuity

> Suppose that $a,c$ are real numbers , $c>0$ and $f$ is defined on $[0,1]$ by $f(x)=x^a \sin (|x|^{-c})$ if $x \neq 0$ and $f(x)=0$ if $x=0.$ Then I have to show that
>   1.$f$ is continuous iff $a>0$ and
>   2.$f'(0)$ exists iff $a>1.$

My Attempt:For (2),  I compute $$f'(0)= \lim_{x \to 0}\dfrac {f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}= \lim_{x \to 0}\dfrac {x^a \sin \frac {1}{x^c}-0}{x-0}= \lim_{x \to 0}x^{a-1} \sin \frac {1}{x^c}.$$ Hence, for $f'(0)$ to exist we must have $a-1>0 \implies a>1.$ Am I going in the right direction?

For (1),If $f$ is continuous at some point ,say at $x=0,$ then $$\lim_{x \to 0+}f(x)=\lim_{x \to 0-}f(x)=f(0)=0.$$ From this , $$\lim_{x \to 0+}f(x)=\lim_{x \to 0+} x^a \sin \frac {1}{x^c}=0.$$ Now I am stuck and not sure how to show $a>0.$

Can someone point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For part $1$, we have $$0\leq\left|\lim_{x\to0^+}x^a\sin(|x|^{-c})\right|\leq\lim_{x\to0^+}x^a.$$The right limit is defined (that is, finite) only when $a\geq 0$, with equality if and only if $a>0$ (why?).

For part $2$, the argument looks good (and even resembles the basic argument for part $1$ that I just gave). Be sure not to stop just short of the full solution (you've shown one implication, so you still have the other direction to show).

Answer (score 0):

Note that both $x^a$ and $\sin\frac1{x^c}$ are continuous on $(0,1]$ for any real $a,c$. Then $f$ is continuous on $[0,1]$ iff $f$ is continuous at $x=0$ if and only if $$\lim_{x\to0^+}f(x)=f(0)=0.$$ You must show that this holds when $a>0,$ and fails when $a\le 0$.

For the second part, you're well on your way. Be sure you show both directions--that is, that $f'(0)$ exists when $a>1$, and that it fails to exist when $0<a\le 1$. (Why don't we need to consider the case that $a\le0$ here?)

Comment: Thanks a lot sir for your valuable input. We do not need to consider the case when $a<0$ as for $a=-b<0$ we see that  $$\lim_{x \to 0}x^{a-1} \sin \frac {1}{x^c}=\lim_{x \to 0} \dfrac {1}{x^{b+1}} \sin \frac {1}{x^c}$$ and we see that $$\lim_{x \to 0} \dfrac {1}{x^{b+1}}$$ does not exist for any choice of $b \in \mathbb R^+$.

Comment: That's true. Even more simply, we showed in part $1$ that $f$ wasn't continuous at $x=0$ when $a\le0$, from which we see that it can't be (right-)differentiable there, either.